# Ubuntu 11.04 appearing like ubuntu 10.10 suddenly

Tags: 11.04

My ubuntu 11.04 set up is appearing like an Ubuntu 10.10, (Gnome 2 rather than Unity) why please?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Possibly a screenshot of what you are seeing? Is your DE appearing like 10.10 default DE? Your question is extreamly vague.

Comment: sorry please it did not occur to me to do so , just too anxious i guess. Thanks anyway.

Comment: click the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/96588/edit) button and upload a screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean in a desktop appearance way, such as no Unity, then your computer has dropped into a fallback mode where graphics are less intensive. To change back (presuming your computer can support Unity, it will if it has had it before) then you will need to log out and at the bottom; choose the desktop environment that you prefer and log in with your usual credentials.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes that is it please.

Comment: @roland please I selected ubuntu out of a list consisting of; recovery console, ubuntu, ubuntu classic, ubuntu safe mode. Which should i pick please?

Comment: I believe that ubuntu will be the option that you want but if it is not simply log out again and try another option.

Comment: If none of the options will load Unity then either your hardware does not support it or you need to install additional drivers; in which case navigate to "additional drivers" in Ubuntu (I think it may be under "administration") if there are new drivers, activate them and restart your system. Once restarted log in to "Ubuntu" again and see if it works, if not report back.

Answer (score 3):

You may have accidentally logged in as Gnome Classic. Try logging out, clicking on the cog next to the login box, and selecting normal Gnome (or Unity if thats what you want).

Comment: I selected ubuntu out of a list consisting of; recovery console, ubuntu, ubuntu classic, ubuntu safe mode. Which should i pick please?

Comment: please I selected ubuntu out of a list consisting of; recovery console, ubuntu, ubuntu classic, ubuntu safe mode. Which should i pick please?